# CSS Positioning & text

Tags: html, css

I've got the CSS code for my register button:

```
.register-button {
    padding:7px 375px;
    background: #3b7aae;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 1px 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.25);
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-100px;
    left:0px;
    text-align:left;
    text-shadow:2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
    .register-button:hover {
    background-color: #4386be;
}



.register-button span {
    display:block;
    font-weight:normal;

}
```

And the HTML looks like:

```
<a class="register-button" href="/register">
                Register today, you won't regret it!
            </a>
```

It then outputs this:

[image]
My question is simple, how can I get it to stay on one single line, rather than like how it is in the picture? I've tried changing the position to fixed and adjusting top; & left; and it just made things worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width of the .register-button to 300px.

Here is a jsFiddle example using your code (http://jsfiddle.net/2WCje/)

CSS:

```
.register-button {
    padding:7px 375px;
    background: #3b7aae;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 0 1px 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-100px;
    left:0px;
    text-align:left;
    text-shadow:2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    width: 300px;/*----------This will line up the text for you-----------*/
}
.register-button:hover {
    background-color: #4386be;
}
.register-button span {
    display:block;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfect. I added the width to the proper width and then I adjusted the "text-align:left;" to text-align:center; and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your padding value from

```
.register-button {
    padding:7px 375px;
```

to something like this

```
.register-button {
    padding:7px 35px;
```